# How to put a VBA formula using dynamic variables capturing Address?

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I am running a Loop to capture the start of Range and end of Range for a particular scenario. After I find my start range and end range, I want to put it as a formula in a cell. For example:

```
Cells(1,1).Formula  "= Min( startrange:endrange)"
```

The above code has assumed the variables as text and instead of putting the cell address these variables are handling, it is pasting the formula as text like this : '= Min( startrange:endrange)'

I have no idea and have tried different approaches I could get from internet like below

```
'    cells(4,4).formula = "=Min("&startrage& :"" & endrange & ")""
'      Cells(4, 4).Formula = "=Min(startrange.value :endrange)"

'Cells(4, 4).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(startrange:endrange)
 '   Cells(4, 4).Formula =  "=Min("&startrange&"&":"& " &endrange&")"
```

where

```
 startrange = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Address(0, 0)
endrange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Address(0, 0)
```

Nothing works.

How can I achieve this? Specially I am also facing error in handling ":".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cells(4,4).formula = "=Min(" & startrage & ":" & endrange & ")"
```